# Deleting/Removing element from a list when comparing to another list Python

Tags: python, list

So I have a good one. I'm trying to build two lists (`ku_coins` and `bin_coins`) of crypto tickers from two different exchanges, but I don't want to double up, so if it appears on both exchanges I want to remove it from `ku_coins`.

A slight complication occurs as Kucoin symbols come in as `AION-BTC`, while Binance symbols come in as `AIONBTC`, but it's no problem.

So firstly, I create the two lists of symbols, which runs fine, no problem. What I then try and do is loop through the Kucoin symbols and convert them to the Binance style symbol, so `AIONBTC` instead of `AION-BTC`. Then if it appears in the Binance list I want to remove it from the Kucoin list. However, it appears to randomly refuse to remove a handful of symbols that match the requirement. For example `AION`.

It removes the majority of doubled up symbols but in AIONs case for example it just won't delete it.

If I just do `print(i)` after this loop:

```
for i in ku_coins:
    if str(i[:-4] + 'BTC') in bin_coins:
```

It will happily print `AION-BTC` as one of the symbols, as it fits the requirement perfectly. However, when I stick the `ku_coins.remove(i)` command in before printing, it suddenly decideds not to print AION suggesting it doesn't match the requirements. And it's doing my head in. Obviously the `remove` command is causing the problem, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any help really appreciated.

```
import requests
import json

ku_dict = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/allTickers').text)
ku_syms = ku_dict['data']['ticker']
ku_coins = []
for x in range(0, len(ku_syms)):
    if ku_syms[x]['symbol'][-3:] == 'BTC':
        ku_coins.append(ku_syms[x]['symbol'])

bin_syms = json.loads(requests.get('https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker').text)
bin_coins = []
for i in bin_syms:
    if i['symbol'][-3:] == 'BTC':
        bin_coins.append(i['symbol'])

ku_coins.sort()
bin_coins.sort()

for i in ku_coins:
    if str(i[:-4] + 'BTC') in bin_coins:
        ku_coins.remove(i)
```

Comment: This is a code smell. Do not modify a list you iterating over.

Comment: as @Fourier is pointing out, do not remove elements from the list you're iterating: store the results and remove them after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, wasn't really aware of that, don't work with many lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@top bantz, @Fourier has already mentioned that you shouldn't modify a list you're iterating over. What you can do in this case is to create a copy of `ku_coins` first then iterate over that, and then remove the element from the original `ku_coins` that matches your `if` condition. See below:

```
ku_coins.sort()
bin_coins.sort()

# Create a copy 
ku_coins_ = ku_coins[:]

# Then iterate over that copy
for i in ku_coins_:
   if str(i[:-4] + 'BTC') in bin_coins:
       ku_coins.remove(i)
```

Comment: Lovely answer thanks mate, wasn't aware about not modifying a list I was iterating through, don't work with many lists

Answer (score 1):

How about modifying the code to:

```
while ku_coins:
    i = ku_coins.pop()
    if str(i[:-4] + 'BTC') in bin_coins:
        pass
    else:
        # do something
```

the `pop()` method removes `i` from the `ku_coins` list

[pop()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-pop/)